# Adding Web Reference in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to c#  can any tell me how to  add a web reference to my project and what kind of Project should i select

Comment: We need more information. What are you trying to create? Is there an existing web service you want to connect to for the web reference?

Comment: "Add Web Reference" should not be used for new development. Use "Add Service Reference" instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A Web reference enables a project to
>   consume one or more XML Web services.
>   Use the Add Web Reference Dialog Box
>   to search for Web services locally, on
>   a local area network, or on the
>   Internet.
>
> After adding a Web reference to your
>   current project, you can call any
>   methods exposed by the Web service.

To add a Web Reference

1. On the Project menu, click Add Web Reference.
2. In the URL box of the Add Web Reference dialog box, type the URL to obtain the service description of the Excel Web Services, such as http:////_vti_bin/excelservice.asmx or http:///_vti_bin/excelservice.asmx. Then click Go to retrieve information about the Web service.
     Note Note:

   You can also open the Add Web Reference dialog box in the Solution Explorer pane by right-clicking References and selecting Add Web Reference.
3. In the Web reference name box, rename the Web reference to ExcelWebService.
4. Click Add Reference to add a Web reference for the target Web service.
5. Visual Studio downloads the service description and generates a proxy class to interface between your application and Excel Web Services.

Read

[How to: Add and Remove Web References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx%28VS.80%29.aspx)