# Adding value to dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

I have web Service method that returns value of one column of a table. I want add that value to my drop down list. Is there any easy way to do it.

Here is my web method that returns all conference_name in conference table.

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Retrieves all Conference")]
        public DataSet GetAllConference()
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            // Create connection object
            OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            try
            {
                oleConn.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT conference_name FROM Conference";
                OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, oleConn);
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Conference");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                oleConn.Close();
            }
            if (dataSet.Tables.Count <= 0)
                return null;
            else
                return dataSet;
        }
```

On user side there will be one dropdown list. How can i add the value return by the web method to the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add web reference of web service in order to call the method, You may  **[read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496253/adding-web-reference-in-c-sharp)** to know how add reference, After adding reference you can call the method adn fill the drop down by the code given below,

```
DataSet ds = wsObject.GetAllConference();
if(ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{
   ddlist.DataTextField = "conference_name";
   ddlist.DataValueField = "conference_name"; //Change field to one you want.
   //ddlist.DataValueField = "IDColumnInTheDataTable"; //un comment after give right column name
   ddlist.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
   ddlist.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: By this statement ddlist.DataValueField = "IDColumnInTheDataTable";